# ¿Cómo puedo normalizar las URL haciendo que terminen siempre con /, que todos los caracteres estén en minúsculas y que no haya acentos?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Estoy creando un código para mostrar el total de vistas de las páginas de mi sitio web leyendo los datos desde [google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics).

Me he llevado la sorpresa de que Google Analytics trata las URLs como diferentes si estas están escritas en mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Por ejemplo, esta sería una URL a la misma página, pero Analytics computa visitas por separado según esté escrita la URL:

- `/JN-08_01-11/`
- `/Jn-08_01-11/`
- `/jN-08_01-11/`
- `/jn-08_01-11/`

Más aún, también estas las trata como diferentes:

- `/JN-08_01-11`
- `/Jn-08_01-11`
- `/jN-08_01-11`
- `/jn-08_01-11`

Aquí tenemos entonces **8 datos diferentes para Google Analytics**, cuando en realidad es la misma URL.

Lo que yo quisiera es crear una regla (¿quizá por `.htaccess`) que me normalice esa situación y que tenga impacto en los datos que maneja Google Analytics. O sea, que cuando alguien escriba la URL de cualquiera de las 8 maneras mencionadas más arriba, ésta se convierta en **`/jn-08_01-11/`**.

Actualmente he usado [este código](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/) para convertir todo a minúscula:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

No sé si sea el más óptimo. Por el momento funciona para la cuestión de las mayúsculas. **Si hay alguna sugerencia mejor, será bienvenida.**

Pero necesito también:

- **Colocar el caracter `/` al final de las URLs escritas por el usuario que no lo tengan**
- **Convertir todas las vocales acentuadas en vocales sin acento**
- **Convertir la `ñ` o la `Ñ` en `n`**

¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

Comment: ¿Tenés acceso al .conf?

Comment: @Mariano, creo que no. Estoy en hosting compartido.

Answer (score 0):

Para forzar a que la url termine en /, puedes utilizar:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

En cuanto a las ñ y los acentos, lo adecuado sería que lo hicieras en la aplicación y no en el .htaccess. Reemplazando los caracteres acentuados y las ñ en la generación de los enlaces (y asegurándote de que el controlador va a poder encontrar la página deseada desde estos "slugs").

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución ideal pasaría por corregir la aplicación de manera que las urls que contiene trabajen siempre del mismo modo (minúsculas, por ejemplo)

Intentar corregirlo mediantes reglas htaccess no es más que poner un parche y no soluciona el problema de raíz (Y puede que llegue a ser un problema por temas de rendimiento)

Para intentar corregir el problema en la aplicación/web hay que distinguir cómo se generan esos enlaces.

1. Son enlaces que se crean dinámicamente mediante alguna función hecha en php, por ejemplo? De ser así la única explicación para que las urls aparezcan de diferente manera es que el código que crea las urls esté duplicado en varios sitios y en cada sitio utilice mayúsculas o minúsculas de diferente manera. Lo suyo sería tener ese código centralizado en un único sitio y hacer que trabaje únicamente con minúsculas.
2. Si son enlaces estáticos (bien puro html o bien string/texto plano dentro de un php), lo que podrías hacer es corregir todos los fuentes, haciendo una sustitución.

Con linux o similar (Una consola [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), o [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/install-win10), por ejemplo) puedes aplicar este comando que debería cambiar todas las urls y hacer que terminen en `/`.

```
perl -i.bkcambiourl -lpe 's/(https?:\/(?:\/[\p{L}0-9.~_!*''();:@&=+$,?%#\[\]-]+)*)(?<![,.;])\/?/\L\1\//gi' `grep -ril http *`
```

Lo tienes que aplicar en la carpeta raíz de tus fuentes.

Para cada fichero cambiado, creará un fichero de backup con la extensión `.bkcambiourl` (que luego puedes borrar una vez verificado todo)

Pero como en cualquier sustitución masiva, haz backup de tu directorio de fuentes.

Comment: Gracias Julio. En mi entorno las URL están normalizadas. Lo que quiero controlar es que cuando un usuario escriba algo en mayúscula por ejemplo todo eso se cambie a minúscula. La web maneja contenido secuencial y ocurre que debido a eso muchas veces los usuarios cambian la URL para ir de un lado a otro y en esos cambios ponen por ejemplo un `J` en mayúscula. Cuando eso ocurre Google Analytics no diferencia esa URL de una que lleva la `j` y eso es lo que quiero controlar.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Añadir la barra al final si no la tuviera
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z]|%[Cc]3%(?:8[19Dd]|9[13AaCc]|[Aa][19Dd]|[Bb][13AaCc]) - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z]|%[Cc]3%(?:8[19Dd]|9[13AaCc]|[Aa][19Dd]|[Bb][13AaCc]) - [S=42]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*+)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*+)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*+)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*+)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*+)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*+)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*+)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*+)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*+)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*+)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*+)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*+)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*+)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*+)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*+)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*+)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*+)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*+)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*+)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*+)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*+)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*+)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*+)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*+)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*+)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*+)Z(.*)$ $1z$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%91(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%[Bb]1(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%81(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%[Aa]1(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%89(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%[Aa]9(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%8[Dd](.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%[Aa][Dd](.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%93(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%[Bb]3(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%9[Aa](.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%9[Cc](.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%[Bb][Aa](.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^%]*+.*?)%[Cc]3%[Bb][Cc](.*)$ $1u$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z]|%[Cc]3%(?:8[19Dd]|9[13AaCc]|[Aa][19Dd]|[Bb][13AaCc]) - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Lo he añadido como una nueva respuesta porque creo que complementa a la anterior (dependiendo desde dónde venga el problema). @A.Cedano, prueba a ver qué tal y si va bien añado las respectivas explicaciones de los cambios