# ¿Cómo puedo implementar una consulta donde se muestre las publicaciones más populares MySQLi/PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy tratando de crear un apartado sobre la **Publicación más popular** entonces pensé en mostrar las entradas de los últimos 10 días, pero esto no me da los resultados deseados, luego pensé en crear una nueva tabla para registrar y contar las visitas de dicho articulo pero al hacerlo de esta manera serían demasiados registros.

Entonces desde la siguiente consulta donde se muestran el detalle del articulo

```
$stmtID = $con->prepare("SELECT ... title FROM news WHERE url=? limit 1");
$stmtID->bind_param("s",$url_true);
$stmtID->execute();
$stmtID->store_result();

$stmtID->bind_result($id_news,
    $title,
    ...
);
if ($stmtID->fetch()) {
    //Detalle del producto
}
```

He agregado una nueva columna llamada `count_visits` en la tabla `news` para que desde ahí se vaya registrando y actualizando las visitas es decir aumentar el campo de recuento en 1 y actualizar en el mismo articulo sin la necesidad de tener que duplicar registros por cada visita, por ejemplo

```
id_news    title   image   count_visits
   1       titu..   img        100
   2       titu..   img        5
   3       titu..   img        1
```

De esta manera parece ser más eficaz y, a la vez ahorrarme demasiados registros de visitas como puedo registrar e incrementar dicha columna por cada vez que se visite dicho articulo y, para así luego realizar una consulta mostrando los últimos 20 artículos con el número mayor de visitas.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT url,image,alt_img,mini_title,mini_description,date_post FROM news WHERE language=? AND active=? order by id_news DESC limit 20");
```

Comment: No termino de entender, ¿cuál es la duda o dónde ocupas ayuda?

Comment: @Aprendiz Me gustaría crear un contador de visitas que se autoincremente pero desde el mismo articulo sin tener que crear una nueva tabla, que vaya contabilizando y actualizando cada vista del articulo en la columna `count_visits` para luego así hacer una nueva consulta y, mostrar los primeros 20 artículos más populares o con más vistas.

Comment: Tener y mantener un contador de visitas **real** no es tan simple como se podría pensar. Por ejemplo un boot que solicita tu sitio miles de veces en un minuto no debe contabilizar como mil visitas por minuto.   Aparte de eso está la cuestión de escribir permanentemente en la BD o en un archivo. Yo usaría para esto Google Analytics, que tiene una API excelente. Si [observas aquí](https://www.deiverbum.org) el widget al pie titulado MÁS VISTOS ESTA SEMANA está hecho en base a datos de Google Analytics.

Comment: @A.Cedano Amigo si tengo implementado Google Analytics lo que quiero es cerar un contador y, actualizar autoincrementar en la misma columna `count_visits` con el objetivo de mostrar las publicaciones más populares o más vistas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sería interesante manejar este tipo de casos usando el servicio Google Analytics. Esto nos daría la ventaja no solo de evitar hacer un track de las visitas por nosotros mismos, lo cual es complicado (imaginemos un bot que solicita nuestra URL 100 veces en un minuto, eso no puede ser contabilizado como 100 visitas en un minuto). Aparte de eso, usar Google Analytics nos permitiría manejarlo todo con un simple archivo JSON que nos guardaría únicamente las `N` URL más vistas que querramos mostrar.

Hay más ventajas, por ejemplo, aplicando filtros, podemos evitar ciertas páginas aventajadas del sitio que no queremos mostrar (como la URL principal que será siempre sí o sí la más visitada) o bien otras URLs que por algún motivo no nos interesa sean mostradas como las más vistas.

Yo tengo implementado esto en mi sitio desde hace un par de años y me funciona de maravilla. Lo comparto aquí por si le puede servir a alguien:

## 1. Instalación inicial

Quizá el paso más trabajoso será instalar la librería de Google Analytics y habilitar la API en la consola de Google, sobre todo si no se tiene experiencia usando las API de Google. En cualquier caso, todo lo que hay que hacer [está explicado aquí](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php?hl=es).

Si ya estamos usando otra API de Google no tenemos que repetir el paso de instalar la librería de `google/apiclient` que es un paquete completo para los servicios de Google como Gmail, Drive, Analytics, etc. En ese caso, solamente tendremos que autorizar en la consola de Google permisos para la API de Analytics, ya que los servicios de Google trabajan por servicios y por scopes en esos servicios.

## 2. Código PHP para obtener los más visitados

Con la API ya instalada vía `composer` o de otro modo y con los permisos otorgados en la consola de Google, empezamos a disfrutar de estos servicios.

El código PHP es muy simple.

```
<?php
    #Este es un archivo de la API de Google
    require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $analytics = initializeAnalytics();
    $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
    getTopPages($profile,$analytics);

    function initializeAnalytics()
    {
        /*
            *Este es un archivo JSON que nos da Google cuando autorizamos el servicio en la consola
            *Hay que descargarlo y ponerlo en un sitio seguro y no accesible del servidor
            *Aquí hay que poner la ruta correcta de ese archivo
        */
        $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '.mycredentials/myprojet-123456790.json';

        /* Crea y configura un nuevo objeto cliente */
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("My Analytics Reporting");
        $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
        $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
        return $analytics;
    }

    function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {
        /* Obtiene el primer ID de perfil */

        /* Obtiene la lista de cuentas para el usuario autorizado*/
        $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
        if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $accounts->getItems();
            $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

            /*Obtiene la lista de propiedades para el usuario autorizado*/
            $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
            ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

            if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
                $items = $properties->getItems();
                $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

                /*Obtiene la lista de vistas (perfiles) para el usuario autorizado*/
                $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
                ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

                if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                    $items = $profiles->getItems();

                    /*Retorna el ID de la primera vista (perfil)*/
                    return $items[0]->getId();

                } else {
                    throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
        }
    }

    function getTopPages($profileId,$analytics) {
        /*Opciones para configurar la petición:
            *max-results: cantidad de páginas que queremos (aquí pedimos solamente 10)
            *dimensions: unicamente el path
            *filters: sirve si queremos excluir alguna página, se usa con expresiones regulares
            *sort: orden ascendente de vistas
            *start-index: aquí pusimos 1 para que excluya la más vista, que estaría en el índice 0 y que la página principal del dominio
        */
        $optParams = array(
            'max-results' => 10,
            'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
            'filters' => 'ga:pagePath!~(evangelios/|feature/comentarios-biblicos/|^/$|biblias.html);ga:pageTitle!~(Homilías por Id)',
            'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
            'start-index'=>1,
        );

        /*Aquí se establece el límite de resultados a obtener
            desde hace 7 días hasta hoy
        */
        $results=
        $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $profileId,
            '7daysAgo',
            'today',
            'ga:pageviews',
            $optParams);

        /*
            Los datos que nos interesan estarán en una clave rows de $results
            que vamos a escribir en un archivo JSON
        */
        $file = new SplFileObject('my-ruta/json/topPages.json', "w");
        $written = $file->fwrite(json_encode($rows,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    }
```

El archivo JSON que acabamos de escribir tiene esta información, son los enlaces, la cantidad de visitas y los títulos de las 10 URLs más visitadas en la franja solicitada (una semana en este caso) al momento en que se ejecutó el código de más arriba:

```
[
   [
      "\/02-02_fiesta_presentacion-del-senor_homilias\/",
      "2018",
      "2 de Febrero: Presentación del Señor-Homilías "
   ],
   [
      "\/lc-02_22-40\/",
      "1272",
      "Lc 8, 19-21: Presentación "
   ],
   [
      "\/liturgia\/tiempo-ordinario\/",
      "853",
      "Tiempo Ordinario "
   ],
   [
      "\/mc-04_21-25\/",
      "504",
      "Mc 4, 21-25: Que brille la Luz "
   ],
   [
      "\/mc-05_21-43\/",
      "459",
      "Mc 5, 21-43: Dos curaciones "
   ],
   [
      "\/mc-05_01-20\/",
      "381",
      "Mc 5,1-20: ¿Cómo te llamas? "
   ],
   [
      "\/mc-04_01-20\/",
      "344",
      "Comentarios homilías Mc 4,1-20: Parábola del Sembrador "
   ],
   [
      "\/jn-13_01-15\/",
      "317",
      "​​Jn 13, 1-15: La última cena de Jesús con sus discípulos: El lavatorio de los pies"
   ],
   [
      "\/mt-05_13-16\/",
      "295",
      "Mt 5, 13-16: Salar e iluminar"
   ],
   [
      "\/mc-04_26-34\/",
      "267",
      "Mc 4, 26-34: Sorprendente Reino"
   ]
]
```

## 3. Mostrar la información

En mi caso la información se muestra en un widget. Simplemente desde el widget se lanza código PHP que lee el JSON mostrado más arriba y presenta el título y como enlace la URL a esa página:

```
function getTopPagesWidget()
{

  $string = file_get_contents("my-ruta/json/topPages.json");
  $json_a = json_decode($string, true);
  /*
      Esto sirve para quitar ciertas palabras 
      que se repiten mucho y no son relevantes para este caso
  */
  $quitar = array("-Comentarios, homilías", " | deiverbum.org", " *deiverbum.org");
  $preURL='<a href="https://www.mi-sitio.org';
  $URL.='<ul>';
    foreach($json_a as $row){
        $URL.='<li>';
$titulo = str_replace($quitar, "", $row[2]);
        $URL.=$preURL.$row[0].'">'.$titulo.' ('.$row[1].')</a>';
        $URL.='</li>';  
    }
        $URL.='</ul>';
    return $URL.'<hr /><span class="nota">*La información se actualiza cada dos horas. <br />El número entre paréntesis representa el total de visitas del enlace en esta semana, basado en datos reales del Servicio Google Analytics™.</span>';
}
```

## 4. Resultado

El resultado es algo parecido a este widget:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## 5. Automatizar el código

El archivo JSON debería actualizarse de acuerdo al tiempo determinado. Aquí he querido mostrar cada dos horas cuáles son las páginas más vistas. Si se quiere una actualización cada hora, cada semana, cada mes, etc. el proceso es muy simple. Hay que programar un cron que ejecute el archivo PHP donde se encuentra el código explicado en el punto 2.

## 6. Dos recomendaciones importantes

Si se va a trabajar con Google Analytics hay dos cosas importantes para dar uniformidad a las URL:

1. Hay que forzar vía `.htaccess` que todas nuestras URL terminen por `/`<sup>1</sup>, porque Analytics computa de forma diferente estas dos URL: `mydominio.com/unaURL` y `mydominio.com/unaURL/`. Esto es vital sobre todo si queremos hacer un conteo global de visitas de las páginas como explicaremos en el punto 7.
2. Hay que forzar vía `.htaccess` que todas las URL sean recibidas en minúscula<sup>2</sup>. Google Analytics va a diferenciar estas dos direcciones: `mydominio.com/unaURL/` y `mydominio.com/unaurl/` y las va a computar como URLs distintas. entonces conviene dar uniformidad a nuestras URL escribiéndolas siempre en minúscula cuando creamos las entradas y forzando a minúscula todo lo que escriba el usuario en la barra del navegador.

## 7. Hay más

Si se está interesado en usar Google Analytics para mostrar el total de visitas de cada una de nuestras páginas, también se puede hacer con un código parecido a este.

Pero aquí el proceso es más complejo, sobre todo porque hay que evitar actualizar esa información cada vez que se visita una página (esto agotaría el límite de solicitudes a la API permitidas). La solución pasaría por guardar la información de cada página en una tabla de nuestra base de datos y lanzar un cron cada `N` horas o una vez al día por ejemplo para actualizar la información.

*That's all folks!*

Espero que sea de ayuda. Yo estoy encantando por como funciona esto y las visitas se basan en datos reales.

---

## Notas:

1. El tema ha sido abordado en esta pregunta:  [¿Cómo puedo normalizar las URL haciendo que terminen siempre con /, que todos los caracteres estén en minúsculas y que no haya acentos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/147077/29967)
2. La dificultad fue planteada en la pregunta:  [Aplicar No Case Sensitive a carpetas/directorios web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/242826/29967)

Comment: fantástico increíble, en ese widget solo se muestra texto o también pueden acceder  como un enlace, sin embargo observo que no se va ha poder utilizar imágenes de la noticia. Se puede captar la url para hacer consultas de solo de las url que coincidan en la columna  `url` para luego hacer un tipo de consulta tipo así `WHERE url=?`

Comment: @Mary la URL se obtiene también, si observas el JSON del punto **2** verás que el primer valor de cada grupo es la URL. Y si observas el código del punto **3** verás que allí se crea un elemento `<a>` con la URL, de modo que desde el widget se puede hacer click sobre cualquiera de las páginas para ir a ella. En cuanto a la imagen, GA no guarda imágenes junto con las URL. Pero esto se podría lograr manteniendo una tabla con cada URL y el `src` de la imagen correspondiente a cada una y mostrarla en base a eso.

Answer (score 1):

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE news(
  id_news int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title varchar(255),
  image varchar(255),
  count_visits int NOT NULL
  );
INSERT INTO news (title) VALUES
  ('Primera'),('Segunda'),('Tercera'),('Cuarta');
```

Te propongo esta solución:

```
UPDATE news
  set count_visits=count_visits+1
  WHERE id_news=1;
```

Tendrás que lanzar esa query contra el servidor MySQL cada vez que un usuario acceda a la URL que estás contabilizando.

Espero que fuera lo que estabas buscando

Comment: Amigo de esa manera es segura no tengo que declarar variables en `$stmtID->bind_param("s",$url_true);` el último si, tendría que hacer con esto `WHERE id_news=?;` lo siguiente `bind_param("i",$id_news);` la duda el lo otro, es decir esto `count_visits=count_visits+1`  no tengo que declarar y, crear variables como se hace con bind_param("i",$id_news);`

Comment: Lo que he respondido ha sido el query a la base de datos, cómo la construyas desde PHP queda a tu elección. La suma no necesitas parametrizarla, el 1 es una constante y el campo ya está en la base de datos, no te lo envían desde fuera; todo lo demás lo recomendable es que sí lo parametrices :)