# Contador de visitas en php suma más visitas de lo normal

Tags: php7

Buenas amigos hoy me encontré con un problema que me tiene un poco pensativo. Resulta que he creado una manera simple de capturar el `referer` y de contar cuantas veces esa `url` a visitado la página.

Ésta es la función:

```
function datosreferer(){
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== null){
    $re = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ;
    $Z = md5($re);
    $A = substr($Z,0,2); 
    $B = substr($Z,16,1); 
    $C = substr($Z,30,1); 
    $D = substr($Z,23,1); 
    $shortcut = $A.$B.$C.$D;
    $contents= false;
    $refer = "./Data/$shortcut";
    if(file_exists($refer) == true){
      $row = file($refer,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
      $referer = $row['0'];
      $count = $row['1'];
      $count++;
      $contents .= $referer."\r\n";
      $contents .= $count;
      file_put_contents($refer,$contents);
    }else{
      $count = 0;
      $contents .= $re."\r\n";
      $contents .= $count;
      file_put_contents($refer,$contents);
    }
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Como pueden ver la manera es muy básica ya que crea un archivo que contiene la url del `referer` si existe y un número que va aumentando si es la misma url, hasta ahí todo bien.

Ésta es la manera en que llamo a la función desde la página donde llegan las visitas:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  @$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
  datosreferer();
}else{
  header('Location:'.$conf['redirect'].'');
}
```

Si el `id` existe en la url se ejecuta la `función` .

El problema está en que por cada visita la función suma más de un número sin que se repitan las visita. Espero me den alguna idea de dónde está el problema.

Comment: coloca tu  $count++; después de la linea file_put_contents($refer,$contents);  haber si eso te corrige este detalle.

Comment: @Cesarin por lógica eso resuelve el echo de que no aumentaría en nada el conteo ...... igual gracias por tu opinión

Comment: En la linea  $count = $row['1']; le estas pasando un valor, y luego le sigue $count++;  esto no haría que incremente en relación al primer valor que recibe  count? ..

Comment: @Cesarin estas en lo correcto al usar $count++ aumenta el valor en una unidad antes de guardarlo . mi problema es que termina aumentando en mas de una ves la variable $contents .= $count; y por cada visita me suma 2 o 3 de mas

Comment: Votaría por cerrar la pregunta por no poder reproducirse, pero al tener recompensa activa la votación está cerrada :( he probado este código en mi entorno de desarrollo y funciona correctamente. La primera vez que pulso en el enlace que carga el PHP me aparece un valor `0`, la segunda vez un `1`, la tercera un valor `2`.

Comment: Si anterior mente me funcionaba bastante bien ahora no se que pasa .

Comment: Aquí tengo el [repositorio actualizado](https://github.com/ojgarciab/333031-stackoverflow-es) y aquí un [entorno de desarrollo de pruebas](https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/ojgarciab/333031-stackoverflow-es). Sólo me ha pasado una vez, usando una máquina Windows (para probar Edge) que el antivirus (officescan) hizo un acceso previo antes del real del navegador, sumándose inicialmente un clic adicional, pero las siguientes veces sólo contaron como una única visita.

Comment: @OscarGarcia si ya lo revise y al parecer el problema radica en otro lado de mi proyecto igual estoy pensando en usar base de datos . gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Si no conoces el problema raíz que provoca ese conteo adicional, hacerlo por bases de datos te arrojará los mismos resultados. Te recomiendo hacer uso de una herramienta de análisis de tráfico, como whireshark, para ver qué te está haciendo las peticiones adicionales que no aparecen en el navegador. También puedes hacer uso del log de acceso para averiguar el origen (así fue como descubrí el acceso previo del antivirus) y cotejar los accesos del log con la cuenta en el archivo.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas Google Analytics para esto? Ellos tienes una API de Reporting que es lo máximo para generar cualquier tipo de informe, además el conteo de las visitas es mucho más real que lo que puedas gestionar tú mismo mediante un archivo. Por ejemplo, GA no te va a contar 10 refresh de la página como 10 visitas, ni te va a contar 5,000 peticiones de un bot a una URL como 5,000 visitas (sí sí, eso ocurre si no tienes reglas de bloqueo, listas negras, etc en tu `.htaccess`). Todo eso un control tan precario como el que tienes lo cuenta como una visita real, cuando no lo es.

Comment: Me ise un enredo con eso de google analytics no pude resolverlo para que me muestre los datos en mi pagina

Comment: Si realmente te interesa explorar la posibilidad de Google Analytics, [aquí tienes un punto de partida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327036/29967). Lo explicado allí te puede servir para dar el primer paso. Ahora bien, usando la API me di cuenta de que esa primera API de GA tiene un error, y es que no reportaba visitas anteriores noviembre de 2013. [Lo reporté como un fallo en Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1772) y hay una solución basada en la API Reporting de Google. Quizá sería bueno poner un paso a paso aquí en forma de pregunta/respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano     Si gracias y realmente en ese tema me enfocare ya que me causa un par de dudas Y siempre es bueno aprender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que veo es que estás matando la entropía del md5.

Al reducir a 5 caracteres resulta que tienes 16^5 posibilidades (poco mas de un millón), pero aunado a que siempre tomas las posiciones 0, 16, 30 y 23 en el mismo orden resulta en una probabilidad muy alta de que cualquier otro referer colisione con esos 5 caracteres, aumentando misteriosamente el contador.

Para demostrarlo, el código siguiente genera cadenas aleatorias de una longitud razonable para un nombre de dominio sin considerar las partes más repetibles como www. y .com; el ejercicio me arroja consistentemente una probabilidad de colisión entre 1% y el 5%. 
Es decir 1 de cada 100 referers va a sumarle a otro referer.

Si en lugar de cadenas aleatorias usaramos palabras de diccionario -como normalmente encontramos en URLs-, la probabilidad aumentaría.

Por lo anterior, e independientemente de que ésa sea la causa de tu problema, deberías usar el hash resultante sin mayor proceso.

```
<?php

$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

$h = array(); // Arreglo de hashes
for($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++){

    $nc = rand(4,20); // Longitud aleatoria, número de caracteres.
    $str = ''; // Cadena aleatoria
    for( $c = 1; $c <= $nc; $c++ )
        $str .= $chars[rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)];

    $md5 = md5($str);
    $k = substr($md5,0,2).substr($md5,16,1).substr($md5,30,1).substr($md5,23,1);
    //echo $str." \t\t=> ".$k.PHP_EOL;

    if( isset($h[$k]) ){ // ¿Existe el hash? ¿Colisionó?
        echo 'Colisión después de '.$i.PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }else 
        $h[$k] = 1;
}
?>
```

Comment: Mas presiso si lo hubieras añadido al código de la pregunta . pero igual gracias

Answer (score 0):

Le agregué  `PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX` a tu `file_put_contents` para ir concatenando sobre el mismo archivo.

Tome el tamaño total del arreglo y le reste 1 para saber cual es la posición donde obtendré el número de visita. Ya que si le haces solo un `sizeOf` te mostrará el número sin contar el número 0 que es donde inicia el array.

Así para saber el tamaño del archivo.

```
$sizeArray = sizeof($row);
```

Así fue para posicionarme en el lugar donde se encuentra el valor del contador.

```
$count = $row[$sizeArray - 1];
```

Aquí se muestra mas claramente a lo que me refiero sobre el arreglo:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'http://localhost/url/contador.html' (length=41)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string 'http://localhost/urlcontador.html' (length=41)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string 'http://localhost/urlcontador.html' (length=41)
  5 => string '2' (length=1)
```

Aquí el código completo.

```
function datosreferer() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== null) {
        $re = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        $Z = md5($re);
        $A = substr($Z, 0, 2);
        $B = substr($Z, 16, 1);
        $C = substr($Z, 30, 1);
        $D = substr($Z, 23, 1);
        $shortcut = $A . $B . $C . $D;
        $contents = false;
        $refer = "./Data/$shortcut";
        if (file_exists($refer) == true) {
            $row = file($refer, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
            $sizeArray = sizeof($row);
            $referer = $row['0'];
            $count = $row[$sizeArray - 1];
            $count++;
            $contents .= "\r\n------------------------" . time() . "------------------------------\r\n"; // esta linea te permite saber a que hora en formato Unix fue la acción (esto es algo extra)
            $contents .= $referer . "\r\n";
            $contents .= $count;
            file_put_contents($refer, $contents . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        } else {
            $count = 0;
            $contents .= $re . "\r\n";
            $contents .= $count;
            file_put_contents($refer, $contents . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: de esta manera por algún motivo no el numero se mantiene en 0 sin importar la cantidad de visitas