# No puedo actualizar un registro en un formulario, intento hacer un contador de visitas con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php7

estoy intentando hacer un contador de visitas pero no se porque motivo no me esta actualizando el registro si todos los datos me están llegando de manera correcta y no me llega nada a la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi código que no me esta funcionando**

```
// La visita del usuario
$view = 1;
$postInt = (int)$post;

// actualizar, registrar la visita del producto
if(isset($postInt)){
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE view SET views = '$view', id_view_product = '$postInt', create_at_view = NOW()"
    );
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':view' => $view,
        ':postInt' => $postInt
    ));

    var_dump($postInt);
    var_dump($view);
    die();
}
```

**Acá pueden ver como esta hecha mi tabla para las visitas**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí pueden ver como los datos si me están llegando correctamente, pero no sucede nada en la BD**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Que quiero hacer ?**
Lo que quiero es un contador de visita que cada vez que un usuario se visite la pagina de *detail.php* se actualice un registro en la *BD* sumándome 1 en cada visita.

NOTA: no se si esta se a la forma correcta de hacer un contador de visitas, pero esta es la forma en que mi lógica me lo permite.

*Un cordial saludos a todos.*

Comment: primero debes validar que exista el registro! si existe lo actualizas si no lo creas! y es mas facil hacer un asi `UPDATE view SET view=sum(view+1) ,  create_at_view= NOW()" where id_view_product = '$postInt'`;

Comment: Un conteo real de visitas no es tan simple, por ejemplo, hoy día hay bots que lanzan cientos o miles de visitas a tu sitio buscando vulnerabilidades, o que lanzan ataques para tumbar el servidor, solicitando miles de veces en segundos una página (¿mil visitas falsas por segundo o colapso de tu BD?). Una opción interesante sería usar Google Analytics. [Aquí hay algunas explicaciones basadas en mi experiencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327036/29967). Es algo que tengo implementado también conectado a la BD, donde mantengo las URL y el total de visitas en una tabla de mi BD.

Comment: Hola @Bryro, tienes razón no me esta funcionando porque no se ha creado un registro. Pero estoy teniendo un poco de problema y es que escribí un código para que me inserte un registro para luego actualizarlo, el problema es que ahora me hace demasiados registros y eso no es lo que yo quiero. Como hago la condición para que solo me inserte un único registro y ya luego que simplemente actualice el numero de visitas que se registran ?