# ¿Alguien tiene idea de como puedo obtener las estadísticas de mi pagina (google Analytics) y mostrarlos en la propia pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-analytics

Estoy creando una pagina web que es un blog y esta tiene un panel de control y quiero agregar una sección llamada Estadísticas donde se muestren las estadísticas de Google Analytics como por ejemplo las vistas totales de la pagina etc.

Comment: Yo tengo hecho algo parecido. [He explicado los pasos aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327036/29967). Solamente que  Google cambió la antigua API a una mucho más completa, si mal no recuerdo se llama `Reporting`, en esa nueva API algunos métodos y formas de obtener los datos se escriben de forma distinta, pero el concepto es el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Dependerá del lenguaje web que utilices para procesar la información.

Aquí tienes un enlace donde está la explicación a PHP:

[Api de informes Hello Analytics para aplicaciones PHP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php?hl=es)

Aquí tienes el enlace si quieres ejecutar el código del lado del cliente directamente en la web:

[Api de informes Hello Analytics en JavaScript para aplicaciones web](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js?hl=es)