# ¿Cómo automatizar la creación de una spreadsheet con las métricas de la campaña de Google Analytics a partir de una lista Source, Campaign y Content?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-reporting

Tengo una hoja de cálculo con la fuente, la campaña y el contenido de la campaña de publicidad que podemos ver los resultados en Google Analytics

```
Source      Campaign                                                        Content
BDD_Aleteia 9-jours-pour-devenir-missionnaire-a-l-ecole-de-marie-madeleine  banniere_email
BDD_Aleteia avec-les-saints-je-prie-mon-ange-gardien                        banniere
BDD_Aleteia communaute-de-prieres-du-matin-rcf                              banniere
BDD_Aleteia marie-qui-defait-les-noeuds                                     banniere
BDD_Aleteia neuvaine-a-saint-antoine-de-padoue                              banniere
```

Sustituyendo los textos de los recuadros rojos, quiero extraer esta información de Google Analytics de este tablero

[image]

en una spreadhseet y reunir todas las métricas como:

```
Source      Campaign                                                        Content        Users    Sessions    Inscriptions GA Communautés rejointes GA
BDD_Aleteia 9-jours-pour-devenir-missionnaire-a-l-ecole-de-marie-madeleine  banniere_email 481  584 ...                     
BDD_Aleteia avec-les-saints-je-prie-mon-ange-gardien                        banniere                            
BDD_Aleteia communaute-de-prieres-du-matin-rcf                              banniere                            
BDD_Aleteia marie-qui-defait-les-noeuds                                     banniere                            
BDD_Aleteia neuvaine-a-saint-antoine-de-padoue                              banniere       601    773 ...   
...
```

¿Hay alguna manera de utilizar la API para evitar hacerlo manualmente como [esto](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/4122563?key=70cca93d4b551809919663254be5ff7f)?

Comment: Puedes combinar perfectamente las APIs de Google Analytics y de Google Sheets para lograr lo que quieres. No obstante, responder a esto sería larguísimo y sería en cierto sentido hacer el trabajo por ti. Hay varios pasos a dar y varias decisiones a tomar como el contexto desde el cual quieres trabajar (¿cliente o servidor?). En base a eso, te decides por el tipo de API. Debes configurar también un proyecto en Google Cloud Plataform, crear un tipo de cuenta entre varios posibles, autorizar las APIs, etc. Todo eso está explicado en la documentación de Google. (...)

Comment: ¿Es así @A.Cedano ? No pensé que fuera tan difícil ... Pero viendo los tutoriales de youtube creo que tienes razón. Seguiré viendo tutoriales.

Comment: (...) Yo uso la API de Google Analytics para estadísticas de visitas en mi sitio web. En mi caso los datos pasan de Google Analytics a una base de datos, es casi lo mismo que quieres, sólo que tú quieres usar Google Sheets como fuente de datos y para ello tendrás que conectar a la API de Google Sheets y pasar allí los datos obtenidos de Anaytcis. [Aquí te dejo una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327036/29967) donde he explicado algunas cosas que quizá pueden darte una idea de lo que hay que hacer.

Comment: La palabra adecuada no es *difícil*. Sino que es un terreno desconocido que tienes que explorar, pero una vez aprendes cómo funcionan las cosas es muy simple y con pocas líneas de código resuelves problemas enormes. Lo más difícil son las configuraciones iniciales, como por ejemplo instalar el paquete de servicios de Google y aprender cómo funciona cada API. Pero la documentación de Google en ese sentido es muy clara y muy completa. Otra cosa que olvidaba, Google actualizó su API de Analytics, que ahora se llama Google Analytics Reporting (el código del enlace está basado en la API anterior)

Comment: Hola, pudiste solucionarlo?